# SetLayout of qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

please, help me to solve this probleme of qt;
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on Login_1 "Login_1", which already has a layout ?

```
Login_1::Login_1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Login_1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //The main windows
    QGridLayout* MainLayout = new QGridLayout();
    //The first ligne (username, line 0)
    QLabel* LbNom = new QLabel("User name");
    QLineEdit* LeNom = new QLineEdit();
    MainLayout->addWidget(LbNom,0,0);
    MainLayout->addWidget(LeNom,0,1);

    //The second line (password, line 1)
    QLabel* LbPassword = new QLabel("Password");
    QLineEdit* LePassword = new QLineEdit(this);
    MainLayout->addWidget(LbPassword,1,0);
    MainLayout->addWidget(LePassword,1,1);

    //Login Button(line 2)
    QPushButton* PbLogin = new QPushButton(this);
    PbLogin->setText("Login");
    MainLayout->addWidget(PbLogin,2,0);
    //setLayout(MainLayout);

}

Login_1::~Login_1()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `ui->setupUi(this);`.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#creating-main-window-components) -- you should be using [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your helping...

I create at first time a new widget:

```
QWidget* Mywidget = new QWidget();
```

After tha, I make for this widget (Mywidget) parent of my odd layout:

```
    QGridLayout* MainLayout = new QGridLayout(Mywidget);
```

And it work